# running react app with aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I try to run the following app with Elastic Beanstalk (EB): https://github.com/SafdarJamal/quiz-app 
I use the default settings in EB and it ends up with "Degraded" health, opening the url returns "502 Bad Gateway nginx" and the status for the ec2 instance is "Following services are not running: web.".

What am I doing wrong? Am I missing some configurations that are necessary for it to run?